# Why was the question “By the end of today” or “By the end of the day” closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [“By the end of today” or “By the end of the day”: which expression is is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/217534/17712) was closed as opinion-based. However I don't see any opinion there: the OP is just asking for which expression is correct and whether one of them happen to be "more correct" than the other one.

I don't have enough rep to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Why would you want to reopen such a poor quality question from 2014? You could at least edit it to correct some of the most obvious issues with before trying to get other people interested in reopening it.

Comment: @ColleenV  date doesn't matter. Why poor quality?

Comment: @ColleenV - I agree it is not a great question, but the issue might set a few users thinking  about it, especially  NNSs.

Comment: You mean other than the complete lack of research/context, the spelling, capitalization and punctuation errors, the formatting problems, and the absence of a question that can be objectively answered?

Comment: @user66974 This site isn’t supposed to be for questions that make NNESs go hmmm. It’s supposed to be for questions that interest “linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”.

Comment: I’m with @ColleenV on this. Franck: of Colleen’s list, the insurmountable one is the last: there is no objectively better formulation; which to use is a matter of opinion (hence the closure as POB). The other issues could be cleaned up by someone with a (very) charitable spirit and editing rights, but no amount of editing can rescue the question from that foundational issue. Josh: we have a different site set up to serve the needs of NNSes. There’s no point in having two if we’re not going to draw a line between them.

Comment: @ColleenV - so NNSs who want to have a better understanding on this issue (and the use of the definite article is an issue indeed in English while it is not in other languages) are not “serious” about English?

Comment: One pattern I’ve noticed, is that when someone starts their response to me with “so,” it is almost certain that they are about to completely misrepresent what I’ve said.

Comment: @ColleenV - no, you havee been crystal clear!!!

Comment: ok I fixed the issue: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/288372/3023

Comment: @user66974 The question about whether “by the end of today” or “by the end of the day” is “more correct” is not an ELU level question, and it’s not about articles. That it might be interesting to EFL speakers to know which one people like better doesn’t make it into an ELU question, regardless of the number of EFL folks who are linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. It doesn’t even come close meeting ELU quality standards.

Comment: @user66974 What's an *NN[E]S?*

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "Non-native speakers"; people learning English as a foreign language.  Usually indicates those with a limited command of the language; EL&U does welcome NNSes who have achieved fluency in the language (e.g. several of our diamond mods and highest-rep users are native speakers of non-English languages, but you'd never know just from reading their prose; they're indistinguishable from native speakers). User66974 aka Josh is one of these, though hints of his Italian-speaking origins do slip through from time to time.  For that reason, he's our resident champion and advocate for NNS

Answer (score 4):

From some of the comments, I understand that the issue was that the question was posted on https://english.stackexchange.com.

I corrected the mistake I reposted it on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/288372/3023

Comment: Thanks for posting a new question instead of trying to get the old one migrated. It’s better to have an author who is actively engaged with a question than to try to revive an old question whose author may not be interested in it any longer.